# How to add an offset to amp-date-picker's [max] date when it's based off another date picker's selected value

Tags: amp-html, amp-date-picker

I'm trying to set the [max] date on one `amp-date-picker` based on another's value but with an offset of 28 days.

I've tried using `event.date(offset=28)` but I just receive the below error because I'm trying to apply it to a date variable and not the date-picker.today function.

```
error.js:205 %s %s amp-bind: Expression eval failed
```

I also tried to add the offset to the date using `amp-bind-macro` but the date is parsed as a string so I receive an `NaN` (in code example below)

```
<!--/* Start date */-->
<amp-date-picker
    type="single"
    layout="container"
    format="YYYY-MM-DD"
    input-selector="[name=startDate]"
    on="
        select:
            AMP.setState({
                binding: {
                    startDate: event.date,
                    maxEndDate: maxEndDateFunc(event.date, 3)
                }
            })">
    <input name="startDate" placeholder="Start date">

</amp-date-picker>

<amp-bind-macro id="maxEndDateFunc" 
    arguments="maxEndDate, maxDays"
    expression="maxEndDate*1+maxDays" />

<!--/* End date */-->
<amp-date-picker
        type="single"
        mode="overlay"
        layout="container"
        format="YYYY-MM-DD"
        input-selector="[name=endDate]"
        [min]="binding.startDate"
        [max]="binding.maxEndDate" 
        on="
            select:
                AMP.setState({
                    binding: {
                        endDate: event.date
                    }
                })">
    <input name="endDate" placeholder="End date">
</amp-date-picker>
```

When I select the 1st May 2019 on the start `date-picker`, I expect it to set the max value of the end `date-picker` to the 28th May 2019 with an offset of `n` days.

Is there any way of doing this without using a range type as setting maximum-nights restricts the min and max dates selected?

Comment: Your `maxEndDateFunc` is returning `NaN`. As far as I can tell you can't use amp expressions to edit the date returned from `amp-date-picker`.